# The JSON sent by Firebase is invalid

Tags: python, json, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
{ name: 'anonymous', text: 'Hello' }
{ name: 'anonymous', text: 'How are you' }
{ name: 'anonymous', text: 'I am fine' }
```

This code is returned by Firebase and I'm getting the error `No JSON object could be decoded`. I think this has to do something with the validity of the JSON format.

I'm getting this JSON data using the Firebase Node.JS SDK. Then I'm passing it to Python using Pyshell. When I use the `json.loads` in python, tt says:

```
C:\Python27>node firebase2.js
{ name: 'anonymous', text: 'Hello' }
{ name: 'anonymous', text: 'How are you' }
{ name: 'anonymous', text: 'I am fine' }
C:\Python27\firebase2.js:40
          if (err) throw err;
                   ^

Error: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
    at PythonShell.parseError (C:\Python27\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:183:17)
    at terminateIfNeeded (C:\Python27\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:98:28)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Python27\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:88:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    ----- Python Traceback -----
    File "my_script.py", line 3, in <module>
      myjson = json.loads(myinput)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
      return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
      obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
      raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
```

Comment: What's the question? Yes, that's invalid JSON, if it's meant to be JSON, in at least four different ways: 1. There's no single root value (e.g., object or array). 2. There are no commas between the objects. 3. Keys aren't in double quotes. 4. Strings aren't in double quotes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, but this data is not generated by me. It is generated by firebase real time database. How do I programmatically format it every time I get the data so that I can process it further?

Comment: @AakashBansal Is this a response from the FCM server? Or a different API call?

Comment: @AL, it is the response directly from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid JSON and I think that your `firebase2.js` is at fault here.

Instead of this:

```
{ name: 'anonymous', text: 'Hello' }
{ name: 'anonymous', text: 'How are you' }
{ name: 'anonymous', text: 'I am fine' }
```

It should output this:

```
[
  { "name": "anonymous", "text": "Hello" },
  { "name": "anonymous", "text": "How are you" },
  { "name": "anonymous", "text": "I am fine" }
]
```

All strings (including object keys) have to be quoted with double quotes. Arrays have to be included in square brackets and array elements need to be delimited with commas.

Check out your `firebase2.js` program and see how it generates its output. If it uses anything else than a single:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(SOME_VARIABLE));
```

Then here's your problem.

In any case, I am more than sure that Firebase is not returning 
`{a:'b'}{c:'d'}` instead of `[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"}]` - this is a typical error of beginners who don't know the JSON format, something hard to believe in the case of one of the biggest API providers in the world.

If you want to know what is the real response then use `curl`:

```
curl -v https://example.com/some/endpoint -H 'auth header' ...
```

and if you see invalid JSON there, then it's time to contact Firebase support.

The JSON format is explained on http://json.org/ - this is the simplest data format in existence.

Answer (score 0):

I got my error after some debugging.

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
  var newPost = snapshot.val();
  newPost = JSON.stringify(newPost);      //this line corrected my error
  });
```

The following line removed the error:

```
newPost = JSON.stringify(newPost);
```

By the way, thanks everyone for guiding me.